# Play: How to validate Json

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Let's suppose we have the following JSON snippet...

```
{
  "name": "Joe",
  "surname": "Cocker",
  "email": "joe.cocker@gmail.com"
}
```

... and want to validate it:

```
object MyObject {

  def validate(jsValue: JsValue) = myReads.reads(jsValue)

  private val myReads: Reads[(String, String, String)] = (
    (__ \ 'name).read[String] ~
    (__ \ 'surname).read[String] ~
    (__ \ 'email).read(email)
  ) tupled
}
```

`myReads.reads(jsValue)` returns either `JsFailure` or `JsSuccess(("Joe", "Cocker", "joe.cocker@gmail.com"))`... but in case of success I don't want my input JSON be transformed into a tuple... I just want to validate it and keep as is. Is that possible?

Comment: Can't you just call `myReads.reads(jsValue)`, check it is a success and then throw away the result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, it sounds like you want a `Reads[JsValue]`?

```
object MyObject {

  def validate(jsValue: JsValue) = myReads.reads(jsValue)

  private val myReads: Reads[JsValue] =
    (__ \ 'name).read[String] ~>
    (__ \ 'surname).read[String] ~>
    (__ \ 'email).read(email) ~>
    implicitly[Reads[JsValue]]
}
```

To explain what's happening here, the `~>` operator is an alias for `andKeep`, which essentially means "if the previous operation was successful, apply the following operation and keep its result, but not the result of the previous one".  It differs from `~`, which is an alias for `and`, in that and combines the two results together with a function (in your case, converting it to a tuple).

Another thing that `and` does is it merges failures.  This may actually be useful to you, in which case, you may want to do this:

```
object MyObject {

  def validate(jsValue: JsValue) = myReads.reads(jsValue)

  private val myReads: Reads[JsValue] = (
    (__ \ 'name).read[String] ~
    (__ \ 'surname).read[String] ~
    (__ \ 'email).read(email)
  ).tupled ~> implicitly[Reads[JsValue]]
}
```

This differs from the above, in that failures from parsing name, surname and email, are all combined together, so if for example, you only sent a `name` property, the failure object will say that `surname` and `email` were missing, whereas in the other solution, it would stop parsing as soon as it found that `surname` was missing and just return that as the message.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to define the extra reader needed to implement James' answer, you can do what Chris suggests in the comments with a simple :

```
def validate(jsValue: JsValue) = myReads.reads(jsValue) map(_=>jsValue)
```

Comment: yes I want the errors, the map will preserve JsFailures but it will drop the parsed json and replace it with the original value wrapped in a Jssuccess